# IIS Access Issue

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis

### WCF Service

I am developing a **WCF Service** and it needs to **communicate** with a com application running on the system.

I have tested the service with ASP.net development server it works fine. now when i run it from IIS the service can't communicate with the com application.

Issue is IIS runs in a different user account 'Application pool', than the one user is logged in. The COM file run on the user account user is logged in. So the that is the reason they have issue communication. Or at least that what i think.

What i did was i created a new application pool in IIS and in advance setting i changed the process model identity to local system. but it did not work....

i need ideas how to make the make the com and the service to run in the same account.

Any idea will be much appropriated.

Comment: What kind of COM object are we talking about (some product like Office OR some self-implemented) Can you change the COM object ? Can you host the COM object in your own Windows Service ? Can you host the WCF Service in a Windows Service instead of IIS ?

Comment: -> COM Object is third party and need to run with other windows application also third party. ->I don't know how to but i don't think so -> I don't know but work with ASP.net development Server.

Comment: that sounds like "mission impossible" without knowing more details about the COM object... even with more details I suspect that you can't do that without resorting to some "hack" which IMHO would be "non-production-quality"...

Comment: I think there has be a way to host an web application that uses a third party com file?

Comment: That is only possible for some very specific circumstances... what you describe does not seem to fit in there and thus is either impossible only doable by "hacking/circumventing security"...

Comment: it gets a bit easier IF you could host the WCF service in a Windows Service... if you could host the WCF service in "normal application (console/winforms/WPF)" then it is certainly possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS not only runs under a separate account, but also runs under a separate login session that is completely separated from the interactive users session. The COM object must be possible to invoke without a user even being logged on if you are to use from IIS.

Comment: Can i run application and com files in the same login session as the iis run on?

Comment: Interactive applications are not meant to be accessed from IIS. Without knowing more about your application and COM object it is hard to help with workarounds.

Comment: IIS only hosts a WCF service and the service access COM object and COM object access another application. Delta stock is the application and DSApi api comes with it.

Comment: Is there any other way to host an WCF Application with out iis?

Comment: Yes, you can host it as a self-hosted service within an interactive application. Look at the [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) class.

Comment: You can also create a windows service that will host your WCF service.

Comment: @TerryDonaghe: Hosting the WCF in a Windows Service wouldn't let the WCF run in the interactive desktop, which is a requirement here.